# How to prove that the coefficients of a power series satisfy a given recurrence condition?

Tags: recurrence-relations, power-series, multinomial-coefficients, formal-power-series

Given nonnegative sequences $(b_j)_{j\ge0}$ and $(u_j)_{j\ge0}$ with $u_0=b_0=1$ and $\sum_{j=0}^{n}u_{j}b_{n-j}=1$ for each $n\ge1$. Let
$$
b(x)=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}(b_{j-1}-b_{j})x^{j}.
$$
Suppose that $\frac{1}{1-b(x)}=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}a_jx^{j}$. I want to find that coefficient of the expansion, i.e. $a_j$. I think $a_j=u_j$ for each $j$, and, by using the given condition $\sum_{j=0}^{n}u_{j}b_{n-j}=1$, I have found that $a_1=u_1$, $a_2=u_2$ and $a_3=u_3$.
For example,
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{1-b(x)}&=1+b(x)+\left(b(x)\right)^2+\dots\\
&=1+\left((1-b_1)x+(b_1-b_2)x^2+\dots\right)+\left(b(x)\right)^2+\dots,
\end{align}
from which it follows that $a_1=1-b_1$. On the other hand, we have from the condition (when $n=1$) that $1=u_0b_1+u_1b_0=b_1+u_1$ implying $u_1=1-b_1$. Thus, $a_1=u_1$.

However, I couldn't come up with a better (a systematic) method to prove in general $a_j=u_j$ for all $j\ge1$. Is there any reference of this? Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry that there were some mistakes in the first version. And the condition wasn't stated clearly. I have revised them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider
$$f(x):=\bigl(1-b(x)\bigr)\cdot \sum_{j=0}^\infty u_jx^j=\Bigl(1+\sum_{i=1}^\infty(b_i-b_{i-1})  x^i \Bigr) \cdot \sum_{j=0}^\infty u_jx^j \,.$$
The constant coefficient in the product $f(x)$ is $u_0 =1$. For $n \ge 1$,
the coefficient of $x^n$ in $f(x)$ is
$$ u_n+ \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} u_j (b_{n-j}-b_{n-j-1})=
\sum_{j=0}^{n} u_j  b_{n-j}-\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} u_j  b_{n-j-1}=1-1=0 \,.$$
thus $f(x)\equiv1$ as needed.

Comment: It's a wonderful proof. Thank you very much. I learned a lot from you.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how to accept an answer?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Thank you very much. I've accepted the answer.